# How to run activity in background in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Could you please guid me how run a background activity/action every 5 seconds.

This activity is running on all screens.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a little more info on the activity you want to run?

Comment: I am working on an app and i would like to check internet connectivity every 5 seconds. I will show a message on the current screen if it is offline.

Comment: Ah! OK. There's a better way. Apple provides some code for a Reachability class. This fires a notification when the network connectivity state changes. You can observe the notification to get an update when the state changes. It's better than continually running a check on a 5 second cycle. Do a search for Reachability in the sample code section of developer.apple.com

Comment: Note that the Readability class is Obj-C but it'll be distinct from your Swift code, you just register to be notified.

Comment: Thank you, but I am already using Reachability, but I would like to know how can I run an activity in background that checks Reachability status every 5 seconds

Comment: You can use `NSTimer` (the typical approach) or GCD dispatch timer (if you really need this to run on background thread), both of which can be found with a quick search online. But to use either of these to check connectivity represents a fundamental misunderstanding of the capabilities of Reachability. With Reachability, register for notification rather than checking every five seconds.

Comment: Ok, actually I am not sure what is the best approach to achieve this goal, so let me explain it is another way.

I need to show the internet connectivity status to the user below the navigation title as shown on the attached image. This status will switch from online to offline (and vis versa) automatically when internet connectivity changed.
http://i.imgur.com/dK40QRr.png
So, is there an optimised way to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Look at the code in `APLViewController.m` and that illustrates how to add observer for [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) notifications. Use that mechanism rather than timers.